# Making Thermocouples With Only One Type of Wire

Tags: thermocouple

Can thermocouples be made with only one type of wire? I wonder if a thermocouple would work if I use two 10-cm copper wires given that their diameters are vastly different. I know that the two copper wires will have the same resistivity, but the large-diameter one will have a much lower resistance than the small-diameter one. My understanding is that it is the difference in resistances, not the difference in resistivities, that allow voltages to be generated by applying heat to the hot junction of a thermocouple.

Comment: Read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermocouple , thermocouples make use of the Seebeck effect: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermoelectric_effect#Seebeck_effect quote: "A thermocouple measures the difference in potential across a hot and cold end for two **dissimilar** materials." So no, the materials must be dissimilar.

Comment: *My understanding is that it is the difference in resistances* Not really, that the different materials have different resistances is more a result of fundamental properties of the materials. A thermocouple works on "thermodynamic chemical potential of charge carriers" (quote from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seebeck_coefficient ).

Comment: You can also just try your theory, twist a thick and a thin copper wire (both without isolation of course) and connect the wires to a mV meter. Heat up the twisted section. Does the voltage change? Repeat with two wires where one is not copper and they can be of the same thickness / resistance if you prefer. Eons ago at University we had to twist our own thermocouples for lab experiments and used them with a digital voltmeter.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie and that’s how you join the theory to reality when you build it and see it.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie You should make your comments an answer.

Comment: I like @Bimpelrekkie's approach; copper vs aluminium should work "fine" (of course, much less effect per temperature difference than commercial thermocouples, but still: work) and both materials are readily available; you'd need to make an array of say ten such junctions which you heat (with a bunsen burner?) and connect (cold side) in series to see a measurable voltage.

Comment: Its output will be 0V independent of temperature. Apart from that, it's fine...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That doesn't work: the Seebeck effect underlying the workings of a thermocouple has nothing to do with the resistance, but with the Seebeck coefficient of the involved materials - to be exact, with the *difference* in them (often called *relative* Seebeck coefficient).

So, you need two different conductive materials.

Comment: Is the reason you need two different types of metals because the two wires of the thermocouple need to have different thermal properties (like how voltage develops across the wire as the temperature gradient changes)?

Comment: no. They need to have different Seebeck coefficients, as said.